# Modify the wsdl in memory and use it in Service.create(..)

Tags: jax-ws, httpurlconnection

I have a JAX-WS and it's WSDL has following line:

```
 <wsp:PolicyReference URI="policy:Xyz-UserNameToken-Plain.xml"/>
```

I had to manually commented above line and put modified WSDL in classpath

My JAX-WS Client code is like:

```
URL wsdlLocation = new URL("host:port/WSServiceImpl/WSService");
QName serviceName = new QName("http://ws2.service.abc.xyz.com/", "WSService");

Service s = Service.create(this.getClass().getResource("WSService.wsdl"), serviceName);
=========================================================================================
WSService wsService = s.getPort(WSService.class);
```

As you see above underlined line reads WSService wsdl file.

I don't want to read manually pre-edited WSDL
I rather would want to READ WSDL URL on the fly and edit it (by commenting

I guess its doable by Reading the wsdl using a `HttpURLConnection` object, modify the wsdl in memory and use it in `Service.create(....)`

From `HttpURLConnection`, i could read WSLD on the fly and create a String form of WSDL which will not have

But the question is how do i convert this string into URL object in runtime??
Because URL is expected in:: `Service.create(URl url, QName qName)`

Can somebody please provide sample code??

Regards,